# Generate random composite key

Tags: perl

I have an array of strings, and an array of dates.
I need to use these as seeds to insert a composite key into a sqlite table.

So far I am doing this:

```
For dates (contains dates from now to past, user selects number of days)
    For name (a unique random subset of a master array)
        Insert
```

Is there a better way of doing this (there always seem to be in perl)

Answer (score 0):

use "rand($#array_name)" function, to get random index of the array you have, then just use that value, which will be different at each time.